# Flutter firebase get documents where today is in between to fields - date range (startDate / endDate)

Tags: firebase, flutter, date, google-cloud-firestore, between

I have some documents in my firestore with "startDate" and "endDate".
Now I want to get every document where today's day is between startDate and endDate.

```
final DateTime dateTime = new DateTime.now();
final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await colRef
    .doc(docId)
    .collection('subCol')
    .where('startDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: dateTime)
    .where('endDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: dateTime)
    .get();
```

The error is very self-explanatory:

> I/flutter ( 5978): 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 490 pos 18: 'hasInequality == field': All where
> filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same
> field. But you have inequality filters on 'FieldPath([startDate])' and
> 'FieldPath([endDate])'.

But there must be a solution for my problem without filtering clientside. Is it perhaps possible to create an index for this and if so, what does it look like? Other approach would be to save anyhow the date range in one field instead of startDate/endDate, but but here I would know even less how to filter it. Such a simple problem in SQL, so hard in Firebase....

Kind regards,

Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, "there must be", but there isn't.  You'll have to be a bit more practical.  I have a similar situation, but in my case, I *know* (my code, my rules) that events are less than a week long.  To reduce the number of documents read in the query, I filter on

```
  .where('startDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: dateTimePlusMaximumEventInterval)
  .where('startDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: dateTimeMinusMaximumEvntInterval)
```

(i.e. less than the maximum Event Interval in the future, and no more than the maximum event length in the past )
...and then do the rest locally.

This has to do with how Firestore uses the indexes to rapidly split results, and shard the data in a way that scales.

Comment: For me, unfortunately, the periods can also be significantly longer. I am also sorry for the double questions, but I had hoped for new opportunities after more than 1 1/2 years. I will probably go to it and filter it locally, since it is (mostly, unfortunately not always) relatively few documents.

I will accept your answer, because it's another possibility to the answers from the other question, of which mine is a duplicate.